# Create array of Positions in JavaScript for google map polyline

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I want to create an array of positions for Google map API to draw poly line on it. Everything is working fine but there is problem with the structure of my array. 
Accept array is :

```
[
        { lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214 },
        { lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821 },
        { lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431 },
        { lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027 }
        ]
```

But my script for generating the array is :

```
var routepos= [];  

 $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                            var latlang = val.split(",");
                            routepos.push({
                                lat:  parseFloat( latlang[0]),
                                lng: parseFloat(latlang[1])});

                        })
```

where data is coming from ajax request on success in JSON Format.

```
["32.578090,74.080100", "32.578533,74.080100", "32.580070,74.080239", "32.582538,74.080368", "32.583433,74.080443", "32.584554,74.080540"]
```

What am I really missing? or why google map api is not accepting my array?

Comment: can you show the  `data`  in `$.each(data`

Comment: its json array 

["32.578090,74.080100", "32.578533,74.080100", "32.580070,74.080239", "32.582538,74.080368", "32.583433,74.080443", "32.584554,74.080540"]

Comment: Better update `array`  on your question

Comment: I think your are missing `jquery` library link .Because your code returning the array was correct .Only jquery is missing

Comment: and what is that?

Comment: See my answer @Ans

Comment: JavaScript always freaks me out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your are missing the  [`jquery`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn0dWSh4PUAhXJs48KHRntBo0QFggtMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjquery.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFnz7C6MAXGLm7pVcOD_LrOjJUUiA) link `$.each` need to jquery for run .You could see the `console.log` its shows `$` is undefined

```js
var data =["32.578090,74.080100", "32.578533,74.080100", "32.580070,74.080239", "32.582538,74.080368", "32.583433,74.080443", "32.584554,74.080540"]
 routepos= [];   
 $.each(data, function (index, val) { // $.each statement required jquery
                            var latlang = val.split(",");
                            routepos.push({
                                lat:  parseFloat( latlang[0]),
                                lng: parseFloat(latlang[1])});

                        })
                        console.log(routepos)
```

```html
<!--This is the jquery link -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For Better use [`map`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjc6MyUiIPUAhUkSo8KHW67A0kQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNHaY16WQvsRJFKI1AN9YJUvUNjsCg) without Jquery

```js
var data =["32.578090,74.080100", "32.578533,74.080100", "32.580070,74.080239", "32.582538,74.080368", "32.583433,74.080443", "32.584554,74.080540"]
var routepos = data.map(a=> ({lat:  parseFloat(a.split(",")[0]), lng: parseFloat(a.split(",")[1])}))
console.log(routepos)
```